# Selenium click on a checkbox -React :: before

Tags: java, html, reactjs, selenium

I am trying to click on a check box, below are some of the things I have tried:

1. `//label[string()=('Notify user')]/i`
2. `//div[@class='b-checkbox']`
3. `//div[@class='b-checkbox']//label//input[@type='checkbox']`

```
    <div class="b-checkbox">
      <label class="">
        <input type="checkbox" value="on"><!-- react-text: 563 -->Notify user<!-- /react-text -->
        <i class="b-custom"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="b-body b-mh-medium"><div class="b-body b-mv-small">
            <fieldset class="b-form-group">
                <label class="currency-input-label" for="currency-input-field">
                    <span class="currency-input-label" disabled="">
                        <span>When should we notify you that funds are low?</span>
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="b-prepend">$</span>
                    <input type="number" class="b-inline b-w-medium b-form-control" id="currency-input-field" value="" disabled="">
                    <span class="b-text-base currency-input-grey-text">Remaining</span>
                </label>
                <span class="b-help b-hide"></span>
                <span class="b-error b-hide"></span>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However I get element  not intractable error. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which method do you use to trigger click event?

Comment: This is a check box, I am trying to click on the box using .click()   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Actions`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='b-checkbox']//label//input[@type='checkbox']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click(element).build().perform();
```

Or `JavascriptExecutor`:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Actions gave me this error selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException  but the js.executor worked.